# Update a value in json column array of objects in postgresql raw query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

I have a json type column in postgreSQL and I want to update the specific field in that json column. Below is the column I want to update in,
`[{"id":"xyyc","answered":false,"payable":true,"productIncentiveCost":{"incentive":0,"cost":0,"dollarIncentive":0,"dollarCost":0},"reward":0,"amountInDollar":0,"delayToNextProduct":"","extraDelayToNextProduct":""}]`.

I want to update the "reward" at 0 index of this column using postgreSQL raw query.

I have tried updating it using update method set and set_json but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
update data
set value = tmp.upd_json_arr
from (
  select 
      jsonb_agg(jsonb_row || '{"reward": 167}') as upd_json_arr
  from data,
      jsonb_array_elements(value) jsonb_row
) tmp;
```

Details:

- First, you need to 'expand' your jsonb array using `jsonb_array_elements()` function. As a result you'll get jsonb rows.
- Then, using concatenation operation you can rewrite a jsonb field: `jsonb_row || '{"reward": 167}'`.
- Finally, `jsonb_agg()` function can help you to flatten all the jsonb rows into an array `upd_json_arr`.
- `upd_json_arr` is used in a `set`-statement.

Here is the [demo](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yvxdstqx).

This [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/295300) shows different ways to manipulate with jsonb fields.